# Get multiple ID's from mysqli_insert_id and insert them to URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form for booking which inserts multiple rows to the table in the database at once. And for each row has its own id (which is auto-generated).
What I'm trying to do, is to fetch the last inserted rows by catching the id using (mysqli_insert_id) and assign them to $last_id then insert it to the URL of which I can use it later to display all rows that are recently added.
But it keeps on getting only one id from the URL in receipt2 page, while if I echo them from the form page, its able to shows all ids of last inserted rows.

Is there any other way of inserting multiple ids in one variable in the URL?
Thanks

```
<?php

$arr = array();
$arr1 = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $name_query = 'name'.$i ;
    $age_query = 'age'.$i ;
    array_push($arr,$_POST[$name_query]);
    array_push($arr1,$_POST[$age_query]);
}

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $curr_name = $arr[$i];
    $curr_age = $arr1[$i];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['s_id'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO orders(ferry_id,user_id,user_name, 
                                user_age, source, destination,date,cost) 
                VALUES('$selected_ferry', '$user_id' , '$curr_name', 
                        '$curr_age', '$source', '$destination', now(),$cost)";

    if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)){

        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
        $fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = '$last_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$fetch_id);  
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
            $hell = $res['order_id'];
            $hell = $res['order_id'];   

        }
        header("location:receipt2.php?order_id1=$hell"); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Err, please show us the code .... or we could play 20 question for a while if you like :)

Comment: ___Guess 1___ You are doing `$somevar = mysqli_insert_id();` Inside a loop. If you are inside a loop, you will need to make `$somevar` an array and do this instead `$somevar[] = mysqli_insert_id();`

Comment: use [PHP array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Change `$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);` to `$last_id[] = mysqli_insert_id($connection);` and the `$last_id` array will contain all of the IDs that were inserted.

Comment: @Dave I have tried to change the code as you have specified, but it seems like $last_id is not recognized after changing $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection) to last_id[] = mysqli_insert_id($connection).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not recognized. Right before your header call add `var_dump($last_id);` and see what it contains.

Comment: @dave var_dump($last_id) prints all last ID's on the form page. I think the problem is in the header ("location: receipt.php?id=$last_id"); it carries only one id instead of two or three or four depending on numbers of bookings.

Comment: You can't pass an array like that. Put the array in a session variable and retrieve it from there on the next page.

Comment: @dave Thank you it has worked, i appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

to

```
$last_id[] = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

and the `$last_id` array will contain all of the IDs that were inserted. Since you want to pass those on to another page  you'll need to put them into a session variable that you may then retrieve on the next page. You can't pass an array via a URL.

Comment: @Pique If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I am pretty new to stackoverflow